# Alamofire 4.3 can't send JSON request

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

Iam Trying to send a JSON request using Alamofire but it's not working as a JSON Request here's my JSON  :

```
{"ClientID":"55050","AdminId":"myemail","Password":"123"}

content-type →  application/json; charset=utf-8
```

and here's my code :

```
import Alamofire

func doLogin(username:String ,password:String) {
    let parameters = ["ClientID":"55050" , "AdminId":username,"Password":password]

    Alamofire.request("myurl.com", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding(options: []) ).responseJSON(completionHandler: {
        response in
        print(response)
    })
```

and here's the response which i am getting

`FAILURE: responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 3." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 3.}))`

Comment: According to the error, the issue is on the response from your server.

Comment: i tried it with postman and it's working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reading the documentation i just need to put header to set the request as application/json

so i added extra parameter header :

```
let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "Authorization": "Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==",
            "Accept": "application/json"
        ]
 Alamofire.request(ApiKeys().login, method : .post , parameters : parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default ,  headers: headers).responseJSON { response in

        }
```

and now it's working perfectly thanks everyone for trying to help :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you must have missed header in your request. So, there has been no response. 
Your header must be a dictionary `[String: String]`.

```
let header = ["Content-Type" : "application/json"]
```

And your sample request should be:

```
Alamofire.request(getCategoryPath, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: header)
        .responseJSON { response in
     guard response.result.error == nil else {
            print(response.result.error!)
}

print(response.result.value)
```

}